# Is any way to check if callbacks registered with ObRegisterCallbacks are still valid?

Tags: c, x86, driver, wdk, wdf

[ObRegisterCallbacks‘s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558692%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) available since Vista SP1, permits to “register a list of callback routines for thread and process handle operations”.

For example you are registering [PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) callback. You can unset it using software like `PC Hunter` becouse of x86 windows do not have kernel level patch guard. And driver did not know that it is no longer called for this callback.

**The questions**:

1. How driver can check that it callback registered with ObRegisterCallbacks is still valid?
2. Is `STATUS_FLT_INSTANCE_ALTITUDE_COLLISION` error during second call of ObRegisterCallbacks is a right way to check callback status?
3. Is any way to get list of all registered callbacks with ObRegisterCallbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How driver can check that it callback registered with ObRegisterCallbacks is still valid? 
>   Is STATUS_FLT_INSTANCE_ALTITUDE_COLLISION error during second call of ObRegisterCallbacks is a right way to check callback status?

From the documentation, if you try to register callback again with same parameters you will get `STATUS_FLT_INSTANCE_ALTITUDE_COLLISION`. Similarly for `PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine` you will get `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER`. This you can use to test if your callback is still registered with system.

Note: For `PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine`, the error invalid parameter also means maximum limit of callbacks is reached.

> Is any way to get list of all registered callbacks with ObRegisterCallbacks?

There isn't any direct API for this.